# How to use multiprocessing in Python for for loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I'm new to Python and multiprocessing, I would like to speed up my current code processing speed as it takes around 8 mins for 80 images. I only show 1 image for this code for reference purpose. I got into know that multiprocessing helps on this and gave it a try but somehow not working as what I expected.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import time
import os
import multiprocessing

img = cv2.imread("C://Users/jason/Desktop/test.bmp")

gry = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

_,blackMask = cv2.threshold(gry, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)

x1 = []
y1 = []

def verticle(mask, y, x):
    vertiPixel = 0
    while(y < mask.shape[0]):
        if (y + 1) == mask.shape[0]:
            break
        else:
            if(mask[y + 1][x] == 255):
                vertiPixel += 1
                y += 1
            else:
                break
            
    y1.append(vertiPixel)
    
def horizontal(mask, y, x):
    horiPixel = 0
    while(x < mask.shape[1]):
        if (x + 1) == mask.shape[1]:
            break
        else:
            if(mask[y][x + 1] == 255):
                horiPixel += 1
                x += 1
            else:
                break
            
    x1.append(horiPixel)

def mask(mask):

    for y in range (mask.shape[0]):
        for x in range (mask.shape[1]):

            if(mask[y][x] == 255):
                verticle(mask, y, x)
                horizontal(mask, y, x)


mask(blackMask)

print(np.average(x1), np.average(y1))
```

This is what I tried to work on my side. Although it's not working, added pool class for multiprocessing but getting None result.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import time
import os
from multiprocessing import Pool

folderDir = "C://Users/ruler/Desktop/testseg/"

total = []

with open('readme.txt', 'w') as f:
    count = 0
    for allImages in os.listdir(folderDir):

        if (allImages.startswith('TRAIN_SET') and allImages.endswith(".bmp")):
            
            img = cv2.imread(os.path.join(folderDir, allImages))

            gry = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

            _,blackMask = cv2.threshold(gry, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)

            x1 = []
            y1 = []

            def verticle(mask, y, x):
                vertiPixel = 0
                while(y < mask.shape[0]):
                    if (y + 1) == mask.shape[0]:
                        break
                    else:
                        if(mask[y + 1][x] == 255):
                            vertiPixel += 1
                            y += 1
                        else:
                            break
                        
                y1.append(vertiPixel)
                
            def horizontal(mask, y, x):
                horiPixel = 0
                while(x < mask.shape[1]):
                    if (x + 1) == mask.shape[1]:
                        break
                    else:
                        if(mask[y][x + 1] == 255):
                            horiPixel += 1
                            x += 1
                        else:
                            break
                        
                x1.append(horiPixel)

            def mask(mask):

                for y in range (mask.shape[0]):
                    for x in range (mask.shape[1]):

                        if(mask[y][x] == 255):
                            verticle(mask, y, x)
                            horizontal(mask, y, x)
                            equation(y,x)

            def equation(y,x):
                a = np.average(y) * (9.9 / 305)
                c = np.average(x) * (9.9 / 305)
        
                final = (a + c) / 2
        
                total.append(final)

            
        if __name__ == "__main__":
            pool = Pool(8)
            print(pool.map(mask, [blackMask] * 3))
            pool.close()
```

Comment: You're manually applying a mask instead of using the opencv operations for that. You don't need to use multiple processes or threads, you need to be less inefficient in the one ting you're doing. Use what OpenCV brings! Probably, around 99.9% of time your program is busy running python, instead of actually doing anything with pixels.

Comment: In my experience, the overhead of multiple processing of the mask function will probably make things slower.  Instead, since you have 80 images you should try to process multiple images in parallel which has a lot less inter-process communications overhead.

Comment: Thanks for your advices. I believe my current code is rough and inefficient, do you have any examples like using opencv operations in my case ?

Comment: What I know that python has multiprocessing and multithreading. In that case, what else can I look for to process multiple images at the same time instead of multiprocessing or multithreading the mask function ?